# Passing value from view(iFrame) to controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I got a problem in passing value from my scope to controller.

**ResourceManagementCtrl Controller**

Here I got a `mdDialog` that shows a partial view

```
$scope.view = function (data) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            locals: { dataToPass: data },
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            templateUrl: '/ResourceManagement/viewres',
            controller: 'ViewingResCtrl',
            fullscreen: true
        }).then(function (data) {
        });
    }
```

**ViewingResCtrl Controller**

```
$scope.data = dataToPass;
$scope.currPage = 0;
$scope.url = "/ViewerJS/#../Uploads/" + $scope.data.filename;
$scope.$watch('currPage', function (newval, oldval) {
   console.log(newval, oldval);
});
```

**viewres.cshtml**

This is my template.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<md-dialog aria-label="Uploading" flex="50" md-whiteframe="10">
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools dark-primary-color">
            <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
        <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" style="overflow:hidden!important;">

            <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen height="500" width="700" id="viewId"></iframe> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="totalPages" id="totalPages">
            <input type="text" ng-model="currPage" id="getpage">
        </div>

    </md-dialog-content>

</md-dialog>
<script>
        function getPage(p) {
            document.getElementById('getpage').value = p;
        }
        function getTotalPage(p) {
            document.getElementById('totalPages').value = p;

        }
</script>
```

I used to put my function `getPage` and `getTotalPage` here because whenever I put it my `ViewingResCtrl` it always return an error but when I put my function in my view everything works fine but my problem is my model `currPage` fail to update whenever I click the next pages in my viewerjs iframe. The DOM is updating but the value in my controller never updates even I monitored it in $watch